# Why don't containers in C++20 have .ssize member function?

Tags: c++, stl, c++20

I am confused as to why STL containers in C++20 do not have a member function `.ssize()`, but instead only way to get a signed size(except obviously casting `.size()` result) is a free function.
I can not think of any "ergonomic" reason since every STL continer(except`forward_list`) contains .size() method.

note: I do not want to get into holy wars over member vs free functions, but it is really confusing that there is a member function named `.size()`, and that there are free functions `size()` and `ssize()`, but no member function named `.ssize()`.

Comment: I think you meant "*holy wars*", but your typo fits right in with the holiday season :)

Comment: Why don't containers in C++20 have a `find()` member function? Instead the only way to search for a value is to use `std::find`!

Comment: @Barry we both know why some STL containers have .find and some do not.

Comment: @cigien tnx,fixed to make it whole year controversial :)

Comment: It is better to keep member functions down to a minimum. (that is basically STL philosophy) `std::ssize()` makes a member function unnecessary. There a move in `C++11` to add free functions to make calling members less necessary.

Comment: not an answer, but you need a customization point, and you don't need a second one just to cast the result to a signed type. That's not super consistent, but it wouldn't be the only place... Stroustrup's opinion is that a.f() and f(a) should be syntactic sugar for the same function call anyway...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some background is described here [P1227](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1227r2.html):

> ... an ssize() member function should be added to all STL containers; this implied by extension that all containers should have ssize() member functions, and the amount of work to do that was strongly resisted by some in attendance.

> At 2018 San Diego, the ssize() member functions did not have as much consensus as a proposal without them, and were removed.

Comment: good that you did not copy this part, people would have thought you are trolling ;) :  I believe that the objection to "P1089+P1227" was that P1227 had a clause stating that an ssize() member function should be added to all STL containers; this implied by extension that all containers should have ssize() member functions, and the amount of work to do that was strongly resisted by some in attendance